# Extra Variable is getting added in json when sended through JAX-rs

Tags: java, rest, serialization, gwt

I am using GWT with the belows jars :
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.4.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.5.4.jar

The class UserReporting view is below :

```
public class UserReportingFilter implements IsSerializable {

public static final String FILTER_ID_KEY = "filter_id";
public static final String USER_ID_KEY = "user_id";
public static final String FILTER_CONTENT_KEY = "filter_content";
public static final String REPORT_VIEW_TYPE = "report_view_type";
public static final String FILTER_NAME_KEY = "filter_name";

@JsonProperty(FILTER_ID_KEY)
private int filterId;

@JsonProperty(USER_ID_KEY)
private int userId;

@JsonProperty(FILTER_CONTENT_KEY)
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringToFilterContentDeserializer.class)
private Map<ReportsFilterName, ReportsFilter> filterContent;

@JsonProperty(REPORT_VIEW_TYPE)
@JsonSerialize(using = ReportViewToStringSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringToReportViewDeserializer.class)
private ReportView reportViewType;

@JsonProperty(FILTER_NAME_KEY)
private String filterName;

public UserReportingFilter() {
    //no-args serialization constructor
}

public UserReportingFilter(int filterId, int userId, Map<ReportsFilterName, ReportsFilter> filterContent, ReportView reportViewType, String filterName) {
    this.filterId = filterId;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.filterContent = filterContent;
    this.reportViewType = reportViewType;
    this.filterName = filterName;
}}
```

The Field ReportView is an enum. Below is the code :

```
public enum ReportView implements IsSerializable {
CHANGES("CHANGES", newArrayList(DATE, ID, CHANGE_TYPE, DN, MO_CLASS, STATUS, MODULE_INSTANCE_NAME, MODULE_NAME, ACTIVATION_NUMBER, CHANGESET_ID, OWNER_USER)),
ANALYSIS("ANALYSIS", newArrayList(DATE, ID, SCENARIO, MODULE_INSTANCE_NAME, CHANGE_OBJECT, MODULE_NAME, OWNER_USER, STATUS));

private final List<ReportsFilterName> supportedFilters;
private final String reportViewName;

ReportView(String reportViewName, List<ReportsFilterName> supportedFilters) {
    this.reportViewName = reportViewName;
    this.supportedFilters = supportedFilters;
}

public boolean isSupported(ReportsFilterName filter) {
    return supportedFilters.contains(filter);
}

public List<ReportsFilterName> getSupportedFilters() {
    return supportedFilters;
}

public String getReportViewName() { return reportViewName; }}
```

The code for sending it to rest API :

```
public long update(T to) {
    Client client = makeClient();
    try {
        return invocationBuilder(client).put(Entity.json(to), Long.class);
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }}
```

The code for calling update is below :

```
public void storeFilter(UserReportingFilter filter, ReportView reportView) {
    Optional<UserReportingFilter> filterToUpdate = getExistingUserFilter(filter);
    int filterId = filterToUpdate.get().getFilterId();
    filter.setFilterId(filterId);
    update(filter);}


private Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder(Client client) {
    WebTarget target = client.target(baseUri);
    return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I recieve the PUT request in server json , one extra parameter u'viewType is added.

```
    { 
      u'user_id': 1, 
      u'filter_id': 0, 
      u'report_view_type': u'CHANGES', 
      u'filter_name': u'CELL', 
      u'viewType': u'CHANGES', 
      u'filter_content': {
        u'DATE': {
          u'specific': False,
          u'startDate': 1544518015529, 
          u'endDate': 1544604415529, 
          u'name': u'DATE',
          u'timeUnit': u'HOUR'
        }
      }
    }
```

This is causing some server logic to fail, I am not sure why this extra paramter is added to json , when it is not sent through client.

Comment: Can you also show the code for `ReportViewToStringSerializer.java` and `IsSerializable.java` ?

Comment: public class ReportViewToStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ReportView> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(ReportView reportView, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
     jsonGenerator.writeString(reportView.name());
    }
}

Comment: public class StringToReportViewDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ReportView> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StringToReportViewDeserializer.class.toString());

    @Override
    public ReportView deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ReportView mapperResult = null;
        try {
            mapperResult = ReportView.valueOf(jsonParser.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
           
        }
        return mapperResult;
    }
}

Comment: And `IsSerializable.java` ?

Comment: This is present in GWT .
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html

Comment: Ah okay - in that case I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, the code all looks fine to me. The only thing I can think of is, did reportViewType used to be called viewType and was renamed?

Comment: (as a quick workaround, you could potentially set your server code to "ignore unknown fields", at least it would stop it breaking for now?)

Comment: Thanks Matt, I found the error , the reportViewType is renamed to viewType at one place.